# how to trigger side drawer open and closed in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

Need to trigger side drawer closed and open. How i can trigger it in nativescript using drawerOpenedEvent and drawerClosedEvent ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var page = topmost().currentPage;
page.getViewById("drawer").toggleDrawerState();
```

Comment: Need to add background grey on swipe left to the radsidedrawer an to remove it on right